# Removing <p> element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a jQuery function that determines the class of an image within a table and acts accordingly. If the image parent doesn't have the class `selected`, it gives it that class and then adds the `td id` to a div (order). If it does have the class `selected`, it should remove the class, which it does, and then remove the p element containing the `td id`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td img').click(function () {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('x')) {
            alert("Seat " + ($(this).parent().attr("id")) + " is taken");
        } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).attr('src', 'images/a.gif');
            $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
            var z = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            $(z).remove();
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).attr('src', 'images/c.gif');
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
            var z = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            $('<p>').attr('id', z).text(z).appendTo('#order');
            return false;
        };
    });
});
```

It works up until removing the `p` element, where it just doesn't. The `p id` is dynamically set and is the same as the `td id`, hence the use of a variable to choose the id.

Comment: use `$('p')` not `$('<p>')`

Comment: Doesn't it need to be $('#' + z).remove();

Comment: If I read your description correctly, you're trying to create a `<p>` element with the same ID as another element?

Comment: You're going to run into trouble with two identical IDs in the DOM. They should be *unique*.

Comment: I would like to suggest using some better indentation, to make code more readable

Comment: @BenM I realised this when I though I'd fixed it and it started deleting `td`s. Changed now, so it appends a suffix

Comment: It is now, wouldn't have thought about making the ids unique strangely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it was a combination of answers on here.

Firstly, the ids weren't unique, so I added a suffix to them:

`var z = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('<p>').attr('id', z+'1' ).text(z).appendTo('#order');'`

Then used the suggestion of `$('#' + z).remove();` but changed it for my new suffix, so it now shows this `$('#' + z+'1').remove();`

All seems to be working now, thanks for your help.